# IntSet array implementation

Tags: c++, arrays

i have following code for implement IntegerSet  Class,idea is that when i insert element it should sort ,and then print it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntSet{
public :
    int n,*x;
public:
    IntSet(int maxelms,int maxval){
        x=new int[1+maxelms];
        n=0;
        x[0]=maxval;
    }
    int size(){ return n;}
    void insert(int t){
        for (int i=0;x[i]<t;i++){
            if (x[i]==t)
                 return ;
        for (int j=n;j>=i;j--)
           x[j+1]=x[j];
           x[i]=t;
           n++;
         }
    }

    void print(){
         for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

             cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
         }
    }
};
int main(){
    IntSet b(11,20);
    b.insert(0);
    b.insert(6);
    b.insert(3);
    b.insert(7);
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(11);
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(18);
    b.insert(13);
    b.insert(16);
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

but problem is  that  when i run,it shows only press any key to continue,what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` code never enters the loop (since the first element in the vector is always larger than whatever has been been passed to the function) and returns without doing anything.

The code is a bit obscure. Look up [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) – this is what you need here.

Apart from that, your code leaks memory since the class doesn’t clear up its memory. Better use `std::vector` instead of manually managed memory.

Answer (score 1):

Donno, just try to run:

```
 IntSet b(11,20);
    b.print();
    b.insert(0);
    b.print();
    b.insert(6);
    b.print();
    b.insert(3);
    b.print();
    b.insert(7);
    b.print();
    b.insert(5);
    b.print();
    b.insert(11);
    b.print();
    b.insert(10);
    b.print();
    b.insert(18);
    b.print();
    b.insert(13);
    b.print();
    b.insert(16);
    b.print();
```

and see what's happen...

Comment: i have another problem,should i open new question?i have changed code,but it also doesn't work